# blackberry widgets and jquery mobile alpha

Tags: jquery, blackberry, jquery-mobile

I've been trying to get jquery mobile alpha to work on my blackberry widgets.

http://jquerymobile.com/

Some of the styling works, but none of the functionality does. Has anyone successfully implemented this?

Comment: checked your bb if your js is turned on ?

Comment: What OS version is on your BlackBerry?  Lower than 4.5 have notoriously bad browsers.

Comment: how do i check if my bb has js turned on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works on Blackberry 6 and above.. Apparently the new Blackberry 6 browser renders with Webkit, which allows jQuery mobile to work. jQuery mobile alpha is also under development, so it will be implemented in the future.

I hate blackberry :(

Answer (score 1):

use opera mini in your blackberry. it supports jQuery mobile up to certain level

Answer (score 1):

I am using jQuery Mobile alpha 4 on BB OS6 for widgets.  The functionality is much better but the rendering is quirky. Text cuts off at the top and bottom. Form elements change colour unexpectedly when you click on them. default fonts is very small in text box.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at jQuery Mobile. It seems geared towards iPhone touch type devices. I am not sure if it is best paradigm for blackberries - most of which don't have touch  capabilities and have different screen config.

However I am interested in other people's experiences...

Answer (score 0):

on the jquery mobile site they say they are releasing a new version for BB 5 . not sure when it will be released.